# full text search - Conjugaisons and genre only

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, stemming

I am using full text search on my search bar in French.

```
formsof(inflectional, word)
```

But it doesn't do exactly what I want. For example, when I enter 'bus' I find 'bois' (bois and bus are verb forms of boire, which is French for "to drink").

I only want my full text search to find conjugations and genre stemming:

Example: actor -> actor, actors, actress, actresses

If I search "acting" I don't want to get "act", "acted", "acts", etc.

Comment: You are using `formsof` that's how it works. Try `contains(column, "bus*")`. For `actor` - `contains(column, "actor*")`, for `actress` - `contains(column, "actr*")`. And if you will search `acting` you will get only `acting`.

Comment: The problem is that I need that for all the words in french dictionary 

I just cant make exception like you just did. I need the genre and conjugaisons of formsof inflectional but without the verbs forms and other thing